# python flask sqlalchemy, i can'trun my db_create.py

Tags: python

Ame getting this error of TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)...where have i gone wrong?? any help i will appreciate ,thanks

thats my db_create.py file

```
from app import db
from models import post

db.create_all()

db.session.add(post("Good", "i\m good","yes","hae"))
db.session.add(post("Good", "hahaha"))
db.session.add(post("Good", "you"))
db.session.add(post("Good", "hahaha"))
```

my model.py file is

```
from app import db

class post(db.Model):
#    table name
    __tablename__ = "signup"

#columns names
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    confirm= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

def __init__(self, username, email, password, confirm):

    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    self.pasword = password
    self.confirm = confirm

def __repr__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    return '<username {}'.format(self.username),     'email{}'.format(self.email),'password{}'.format(self.password)
```

this is my **init**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "my previous"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///signup.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `__init__` method in your post model. Just use the `__init__` method inherited from `db.Model` and you should be fine.

But then I believe you'd need to modify your `db_create.py` a bit:

For example:

```
db.session.add(post(username="User", email="user@email.com", password="password", confirm="Yes"))
```

Also you need to remember to `commit` your changes:

```
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks Gohn67 lemme try that